# How to fix position of CSS elements?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to create a website with a tile layout, similar to the new Windows style. https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/jquery4u/2013/03/metro-template.png <- kind of like this, except that in my case:

1. each tile is the same size (square) (.box)
2. The text should be in the centered in the tile (.center-box-content)
3. each tile should entail two buttons in its lower right corner, in addition to the text (.lower-right-box-content)
   The buttons are edit and trash icons, so that the text in the tiles can be changed.

I have accomplished this, but the problem is: *The buttons seem to be dependent on the text length.*

I've assigned them an absolute position in the css file, yet they don't stay put.

If the text in the tile is longer, they move all the way past/beyond the tile's borders, which they shouldn't surpass. It's a complete mess. I have tried everything but I can not find a solution. I am hoping that you guys can take a look and maybe see what I am missing? Here's my CSS Code:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
}


.center-box-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.lower-right-box-content {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    padding: 2px;
    bottom: -60px;
    right: -5px;
}

.red-box {
    background-color: indianred;
}

.blue-box {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.green-box {
    background-color: mediumseagreen;

}
```

Here is my HTML Code: (The PHP bit just reads out the text from the data base, which is an event name, event description, and event date)

```
 <!--the entire square tile -->
 <div class="box red-box" height="100%" width="100%">
      <!--this centers the text within the tile -->
      <div class="center-box-content">
      <!--echo the name -->
      <b><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></b>

      <!--echo the description -->
      <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>

      <br> • <!--echo the date -->
      <?php echo $row["date"]; ?> •

          <!--edit and delete button in the lower right corner of the tile -->
          <!--this is the part that keeps moving as the text gets longer -->
          <div class="lower-right-box-content">
               Upcoming Events <span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>
               <a href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-pencil" role="button"> </span>
                </a>

                <a href="deleteevent.php?id=<?php echo $row["eventid"];?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button"></span>
                </span>

                </a>
           </div>


       </div>
</div>
    <?php };
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ideal management of "box" today we use the grid. One example css for 6-columns grid:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Ariel', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #faf3bc;
  background-color: #0976B2;
}

.grid_1 { width: 15.625%; } /* 125px/800px = 15.625% */
.grid_2 { width: 32.5%; } /* 260px/800px = 32.5% */
.grid_3 { width: 49.375%; } /* 395px/800px = 49.375% */
.grid_4 { width: 65.625%; } /* 525px/800px = 65.625% */
.grid_5 { width: 83.125%; } /* 665px/800px = 83.125% */
.grid_6 { width: 100%; } /* 800px/800px = 100% */

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  /* margin-right: 1.25%; */
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.last {margin-right:0; }

.container{
  clear:both;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0% 0;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:link {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#faf3bc; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */

a.selected {color:#ffffff;}  /* selected link */

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.form-input {
  height: 30px;
}
   @media screen and (max-width : 705px) {
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  width: 100%;
}}
```

HTML for 3 "box" in raw:

```
<div class='grid_2'>
</div>
<div class='grid_2'>
</div>
<div class='grid_2 last'>
</div>
```

HTML for 2 "box" in raw:

```
<div class='grid_3'>
</div>
<div class='grid_3 last'>
</div>
```

Maybe you need more grid-columns, go ahead, learn responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

Is the square the *direct* parent of those absolutely positioned elements? It should be, and it needs to have `position: relative` for the absolute position to work.

And erase the `float` from those elements - it doesn't make sense for absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/6ff81hp2/)

You need to set the `.lower-right-box-content` to `position:relative` and then make the buttons absolute positioned.

```
 <div class="lower-right-box-content">
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-right:40px;text-align:justify;">  Upcoming Events longggg text does not matter </div>
         <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-pencil" role="button" style='position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:5px;'> </span>
         </a>

          <a href="deleteevent.php?id=<?php echo $row["eventid"];?>">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:20px;">
           </span>
          </a
       </div>
</div>
```

I have used inline styles for clarity. Please update the styles in stylesheet with appropriate selectors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the buttons in their own `div`.
2. Add `position: relative` to the box.
3. Use `position: absolute` to place the text and buttons to the bottom.
4. To ensure longer text does not overlap with the buttons, add some padding to the text.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2px;
  color: whitesmoke;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.center-box-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.upcoming {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 30px; /* ensure the text clears the buttons */
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.red-box {
  background-color: indianred;
}

.blue-box {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.green-box {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="box red-box">
  <div class="center-box-content">
    <b>Name</b>
    <br>Description
    <br> • Date •
  </div>
  <div class="lower-right-box-content">
    <span class="upcoming">Upcoming events</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-pencil" role="button"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box red-box">
  <div class="center-box-content">
    <b>Name</b>
    <br>Description
    <br> • Date •
  </div>
  <div class="lower-right-box-content">
    <span class="upcoming">Upcoming events events events</span>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil glyphicon-pencil" role="button"></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyphicon-trash" role="button"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```